# Program received signal SIGSEGV while reading a file

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I want to read a file named pvt.txt and just print it to the screen. But when the program runs it always showed "Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference."

It's a fortran 90 code, just a simple code but always showed error like that. I can write a file, but I can't read it in the program. I just write a simple code to try, but it still doesn't work.

the file pvt.txt is located in the same folder with the program.

```
program reservoir_sim
    implicit none

     integer a, b, c

     open(unit=10, file='pvt.txt')

        read(10,*) a, b, c

        print*, a, b, c

     close(10)

end program reservoir_sim
```

In the pvt.txt file's just wrote "1, 2, 3", but it still doesn't work

Comment: We wiil need more. We need your compiler version, operating system version and similar. Please compile your code for error checking (`gfortran -g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all`). If available, try valgrind. If available, try gdb to locate the location of the fault.

Comment: Also check the IOSTAT of the OPEN statement. Do you start your program from the directory where the file pvt.txt resides? Ar the permissions of the file so that you are allowed to read it?

Comment: Thanks for you both, I've already solve the problem by changing my compiler to G95

Comment: Is the record in your data file properly terminated?  That is, is your data file "1, 2, 3EOF"?  Changing to g95 has a few disadvantageous such as it hasn't seen any development in years, and can paper over bugs.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only give evets 1 upvote. This has not solved your problem - it has just hidden it so that it will come out and bite you later